# Does Kotlin have any generic constraints other than upper bounds?

Tags: generics, kotlin

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints says

> The most common type of constraint [on a type parameter] is an upper bound

but doesn't list any others. Are there any other constraints on type parameters supported in Kotlin, or planned in future (except for type classes, which I know about)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time (as of Kotlin 1.2) no other constraints are supported, but it's possible that other constraint types will be added in the future.